Why do we reduce a body to its center of mass when calculating gain/loss of gravitational potential energy?
Say a rod of length L is initially held horizontally and hinged at a point 2L above the surface of the Earth. This rod is then released. The question is then to calculate its rotational kinetic energy when it's rotated 90 degrees and is vertical.
My textbook just conserves mechanical energy by reducing the rod to its center of mass and equating KE to the difference of the potential energies of the COM (vertical and horizontal). This doesn't make sense to me because the same textbook also never reduces a body to its center of mass during calculations of field and potential energy in the actual Gravitation chapter.
What exactly is happening here?

Consider a mass at height $h$ above the surface and another mass at height $(h+L)$ that are connected by a massless rod. The potential energy of the lower mass is $-mgh$ and the potential energy of the upper mass is $-mg(h+L)$. The total potential energy of the assembly is $(-2 \ mgh - mgL)$. The potential energy of the same total amount of mass $2m$ located at the centre of the rod is $$-2 \ mg \left(h+\frac{L}{2}\right) = \left(-2 \ mgh -2 \ mg \frac{L}{2}\right) = (-2 \ mgh - mgL),$$ which is the same as the two separate masses. For a rod with mass distributed equally along its length, for any distance below the centre of mass there is an equal mass the same distance above the centre of mass. Therefore we can treat the potential energy of the rod, as if all the mass is at the centre of mass of the rod.
P.S.  The above is using the approximate gravitational potential energy equation $mgh$ where $h$ is sufficiently small that $g$ is considered to be constant to a reasonable approximation. This gives a linear relationship between gravitational potential and height and as a result we can treat the rod as a point particle.
Over large changes in height, $g$ is not constant and the acceleration due to gravity is $\dfrac{-GM}{R^2}$ and is proportional to $h^{-2}$. The result is that the potential energy height of a large object like the Moon, does not necessarily coincide with the centre of gravity. This is a tidal effect and can result in a gravitational torque being felt by a large object with a non uniform density distribution.

KDP's answer explains, in elementary terms, why this reduction is acceptable for a uniform rod in a uniform field. This is an elaboration of that answer in case you prefer a more formal derivation.
If the gravitational potential at $\mathbf{x}$ is $\Phi(\mathbf{x})$ and the density at any point inside an object is $\rho(\mathbf{x})$, then the gravitational potential energy of the object, relative to the zero potential level, is
$$U = \iiint \Phi(\mathbf{x})\rho(\mathbf{x})\,dV,$$ where the integrals are over the object.
In general, changing the density function $\rho$ -- changing where the mass is -- changes the potential energy. In particular, you cannot normally replace the density function $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ with the delta function $m\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_{cm}})$, where
$$\mathbf{x_{cm}} = \frac{1}{m}\iiint \mathbf{x}\rho(\mathbf{x})\,dV.$$ However, in the case of a uniform gravitational field where, for some constant vector $\mathbf{g}$, $V(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{x}$, you can make this replacement. This is derived as follows
$$\begin{align}
U &= \iiint \Phi(\mathbf{x})\rho(\mathbf{x})\,dV \\
&= \iiint (\mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{x})\rho(\mathbf{x})\,dV \\
&= \mathbf{g} \cdot \iiint \mathbf{x} \rho(\mathbf{x})\,dV \\
&= \mathbf{g} \cdot m \mathbf{x_{cm}} \\
&= \mathbf{g} \cdot \iiint m\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_{cm}})\mathbf{x}\,dV \\
&= \iiint (\mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{x})m\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_{cm}})\,dV \\
&= \iiint \Phi(\mathbf{x})m\delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_{cm}})\,dV.
\end{align}$$
Thus, in a uniform gravitational field, the potential energy of an object can be calculated by assuming it is a point mass. However, this derivation would fail for a general $\Phi$.

When resolving KE of a rigid body the choice of reference point where velocity is calculated and the mass moment of inertia is resolved about are arbitrary.
Specifically, a rod of length $\ell$ that is pivoted about one end has the following properties using both the pivot and the center of mass as reference points
$$\begin{array}{r|c|c}
\text{quantity} & \text{about COM} & \text{about pivot} \\
\hline
\text{linear velocity} & v_C = \omega \tfrac{\ell}{2} & v_P = 0 \\
\text{MMOI} & I_C = \tfrac{m}{12} \ell^2 & I_P = \tfrac{m}{3} \ell^2  \\
\text{total KE} & K_C = \tfrac{1}{2}m v_C^2 + \tfrac{1}{2} I_C\, \omega^2 & K_P = \tfrac{1}{2}m v_P^2 + \tfrac{1}{2} I_P\, \omega^2 \\
& = \tfrac{1}{6} m \ell^2 \omega^2 & = \tfrac{1}{6} m \ell^2 \omega^2
\end{array}$$
As you can see the result is the same. For kinetic energy, the body cannot be reduced to a point mass, as the rotational component does not vanish at any location in space.
Regarding potential energy from a uniform gravitational field, only_ the position of the center of mass matters as the body's orientation does not affect the potential energy.
$$ PE = m\, g\, y_C $$
which means indeed the body can be reduced down to a point mass.

A real object in a gravitational field has some potential energy (we assume the gravitational field to be uniform over the relatively small size of the object). Now take a point object with zero size but of the same mass, and place it in the gravitational field so that it has the same potential energy as the real object - it should be placed at the center of mass of the real object. The center of mass is the "average position" of the matter in the object. There are some points above the center of mass with higher potential and some below with lower potential, but the potential of the center of mass is the average potential over the whole object. You could do a mass-weighted average of the potential energies of every speck of matter in the object, but the center of mass already takes care of the "mass-weighted average" part, meaning calculating the potential energy of the CoM alone is sufficient.
In short, finding the "average potential" of each bit of mass is the same as finding the potential energy of the "average position" of mass.
